# Superimpose a stream on top of a byte array

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, binary-data

Is there any way in C#/.NET to "superimpose" - or map - a `MemoryStream` on top of an existing `byte[]` in-place, so that the data is not being needlessly copied?

In trying to convert a `byte[]` into a stream, the standard solution is to use the `MemoryStream` and its `Write` function like so:

```
byte[] myArray = new byte[10]; // or, e.g. retrieve from DB
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Write(myArray, 0, myArray.Length);
```

Alternatively, this can be shortened to:

```
byte[] myArray = new byte[10]; // or, e.g. retrieve from DB
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(myArray);
```

which is really the same thing.

This has the problem of having to copy the entire content of the array into the stream, thus using up 2X amount of memory. Considering that the byte array can be quite large, this seems unsatisfactoy. The data is already in memory, in a contiguous block, so...

Can a memory stream be somehow mapped onto an array of bytes in-place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `MemoryStream` constructor you mentioned in the second block actually does what you want.  It saves the array you provide and uses that as the backing buffer for the stream.  You can modify the array and those changes will be reflected by the stream if those bytes are still yet to be read.

Here's a minimal reproducible example to demonstrate this.

```cs
byte[] source = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(source);

// If the constructor made a copy, the stream won't be
// affected and it will output 0 below.
source[0] = 10;

byte b = (byte)stream.ReadByte();

Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Output:

> 10

[Try it out!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NM06GG)

Be aware that the stream cannot grow when you use that constructor.  According to its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_MemoryStream__ctor_System_Byte___):

> The length of the stream cannot be set to a value greater than the initial length of the specified byte array; however, the stream can be truncated (see SetLength).

Allowing it to grow would break the expectation that it's using that buffer because growing would require allocating a new array and copying the data to it.